# How to recalculate order subtotal ,on Woocommerce checkout page, on custom field change?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

in woocommerce checkout page i am going to add two custom fields of type date. How can i recalculate the order subtotal every time the date filled changes? For example if the order subtotal is 10€ then if the first date field is choosed the order subtotal will double and become 20€ and if the second field is chosen too the order subtotal will triple and become 30€.

I have found javascript that triggers an update on checkout page via ajax and that is

```
jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
```

so i can call it every time a change in the date fields happen

but then what hook am i going to call for recalculating order Subtotal and how am i going to have access to the date fields that are custom in order to check if they have content and change accordingly the order subtotal value?

As per your request the code for adding custom date field in the checkout page is

```
    function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
        
        echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>'.__('My Field').'</h3>';
                    
        woocommerce_form_field( 'date1', array( 
            'type'          => 'date', 
            'class'         => array('my-field-class orm-row-wide'), 
            'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
            'required'      => true,
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter a date'),
            ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));
        echo '</div>';
    }
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes','my_custom_checkout_field');

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 10, 1);

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    if ( ! is_checkout() )
        return;

    if(isset($_POST['date1']???????)){
        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            ## Price calculation ##
            $price = $cart_item['data']->price *2;
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price ); 
            
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is i can not read the $_POST['date1']  beacause prbably it is not posted. how can i read the "date1" in order to decide if i will double the price of the cart?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on the cart page to recalculate the totals:

```
jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').trigger("click");
```

However, I did not understand how you created the field, please add some code to your post - I hope you are not changing the price by using JS? This can be manipulated by the user.

Comment: Hi i entered the code on how to add custom field date on checkout page

Comment: The code is not complete, how do you want to change the price? Ajax? JS? While it is possible to do it with Ajax, I would suggest your customer doing price changes on the product page before entering the cart. [Here](https://sarkware.com/woocommerce-change-product-price-dynamically-while-adding-to-cart-without-using-plugins/) is a working example, same but different.

Comment: Dear Chrostip, i am not in cart page i am on the checkout page so this jquery is not usefull